# Change name of input field

Tags: jquery, forms, input

So I know I'm asking a somewhat basic question, but it's been rather difficult to search for as I don't know what to call what I'm talking about (I know label is a tag and searching "label" yields results I don't want).

So I have a basic form, with an input.  I want to use jquery to change the name of the input field.  Here's a watered down version of the line.

```
<form>
<div id="ent1">Name <input type="text"> <button type="button"> Just a button </button></div>
</form>
```

How do I change "name" to something else like "computer" or something using jquery?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

Use a label tag for the label and then use Jquery to find it using the below.

```
<form>
<div id="ent1">
    <label for="name">Name</label>
    <input id="name" type="text">
    <button type="button"> Just a button </button>
</div>
</form>

$("label[for='name']").text = "new value"
```

Comment: welcome to stackoverflow! in general, code-only answers are discouraged... better if you can include some explanation as to how this fixes the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It is easier to wrap it in a element like span

```
<div id="ent1"><span class="label">Name</span> <input type="text"> <button type="button"> Just a button </button></div>
```

then

```
$('#ent1 .label').text('new label')
```

Comment: Ah, alright. I was thinking along those lines with the label tag but weird things happened. This makes sense.  I'll implement this shortly and report back.